# Margin 8 dp everywhere, top, right, left and bottom

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I want to have 8dp margin everywhere, top, left, right and bottom, so I set Layour_Margin all 8 dp, check my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.MainFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleViewRandom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

but this no work good, check how it's look, on top i dont have a margin

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvlzf.png)

**android:layout_margin="8dp" in ROOT layout no help**

app_bar_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You xml is ok (you could remove `layout_marginEnd` though), the pb is guess is from your toolbar overlapping your container, so make sure your container is underneath your toolbar and not below it (maybe a relative layout to be replaced with a linerar layout)

Comment: good idea, I edit and put my app_bar_main, I don't see anything wrong,

Comment: as i saif you need to add your content_main below your toolbar, coordinator layout act as a relative layout by default not a linear layout

Comment: helped, @SamuelEminet I can accept your answer if u make a answer :D

Comment: I guess you ca make +1 from my comments, enough for me ;)

Comment: not enought repotation for +1 comment ;/ can only accept

Answer (score 1):

**Easy Work**

You can add **`android:layout_margin="8dp"`** in your **ROOT** layout only.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleViewRandom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: still this same, no margin on TOP ;/

Comment: @jackfield `Clean-Rebuild` and run

Comment: no helps, even I have set 50dp margin in root, top still no margin

Comment: Glad to see you fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycleViewRandom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: still no margin on TOP :/

Comment: can you provide your complete xml?